# Comunicación entre componentes en VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo 2 componentes dentro de /resources/assets/js/components, el primero tiene:

```
 <template>
    <div class="inline">
              <button @click="getDataCategory(category)" :class="is_active == category.id ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-default' " v-for='category in categories' class='btn btn-space'>{{category.name}}</button>     
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import BaseUrlMixin from '../mixins/baseUrl.js'; 

    export default { 
        mixins: [BaseUrlMixin],           
        data(){
            return{
               id_tournament:null,
               categories:[],
               data_category: false, 
               is_active: false, 
               show_data: "",
            }
        },
        methods: {             
          getDataCategory: function(category){
              this.is_active = category.id;
              this.show_data = {
                  'category':category.name
              };
              this.data_category = true;
          }
        }, 
    }
</script>
```

La idea es que al hacer click en el boton, llame a getDataCategory() y ahi setear this.show_data como se ve, y hasta aca funciona, ahora necesito pasar ese this.show_data a otro componente que es el siguiente. Quiero usar como se ve en el form el if="show_data" tiene valores mostrar el formulario. (Entiendo que se puede poner este componente dentro del otro, pero por cuestion de estructura del template no puedo y necesito esta comunicación.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="store()" :if="show_data">
          <label for="">Cantidad de fechas</label>  
          <input type="text" v-model="date" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' min="1" max="50" required="">
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' >
              <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Guardar
          </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
       data(){
            return{
               id_tournament:null,
               date:'',
            }
        },
        methods: {
        },
        mounted() {     

            this.getIdTournament();
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear un "Bus" para enviar las comunicaciones entre componentes que no tengan relación padre-hijo entre ellos, básicamente es una instancia de Vue vacía:

```
var bus = new Vue()
```

a continuación haces el `$emit` desde donde quieres enviar la información:

```
// in component A's method
bus.$emit('id-selected', 1)
```

así lo recibes en el componente que desees:

```
// in component B's created hook
bus.$on('id-selected', function (id) {
  // ...
})
```

Todo esto fue tomado de la [documentación](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication), aunque ya lo he usado en la práctica también.

Comment: Me podés ayudar con mi ejemplo?. Recien estoy empezando con esto y no se como pasar el show_data con bus... gracias. @Shaz

Comment: Realmente no tiene nada de complicado, simplemente la primera línea la debes poner donde la puedan "leer" todos los componentes, o lo puedes exportar o poner en cada componente implicado, la segunda línea la pones en el método getDataCategory del primer componente y la última en el componente que recibe, aquí puedes ver otro ejemplo: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/ la idea es enseñarte a pescar, no darte el pescado.

Comment: Anduvo perfecto!!! Gracias.

Comment: @Shaz ¿qué es una "relación padre-hijo" entre componentes Vue?

Comment: @Gibrán en la documentación está la respuesta: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#ad

Answer (score 1):

Las dos maneras más comunes de establecer comunicación entre componentes en Vue es mediante el patrón de bus de eventos y el patrón de gestión de estado.

- **Patrón de bus de eventos** *(Event Bus Pattern)*: Como menciona Shaz, consiste básicamente en la creación de una
  instancia de Vue (*bus*) la cual permite a componentes, no relacionados, comunicarse entre ellos. La comunicación se da mediante publicaciones y suscripciones al bus por parte de dichos componentes.
- **Patrón de gestión de estado** (*State Management Pattern*): 
  Consiste en la creación de una tienda (*store*) centralizada para todos los componentes de una aplicación.

Dependiendo de la complejidad de la aplicación se debe de escoger que es lo que mejor se ajusta a las necesidades. Normalmente, el bus de eventos se utiliza más para la comunicación entre componentes aislados que no necesariamente alteran el estado de la aplicación.

Cuando una aplicación empieza a crecer, utilizar un bus se vuelve cada vez más difícil de mantener y es cuando un patrón de gestión de estado se vuelve útil.
El recomendado es [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/), el cual es mantenido por Evan, el creador de Vue.